# Jquery upload multifile just uploaded the first select file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this plugin to upload multifile [fyneworks](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multifile/). My problem is like this :

```
- Select one or more e:g 2 files on browse button, then I get those files
- I clicked again, and choose a lot of file e/g 1 file, on preview I got three.
- But when uploaaded, I just got the two image which is the first select.
```

This is my code :
I have a div to display menu upload like this:

```
$(document).on("click", '#menu_container', function () {
        var this_url = $(this).attr("href");
        $.post(this_url, {}, function (data) {
            $('#content').html(data);
            $('#file').addClass("multi with-preview");
            $('#file').MultiFile({
                list: "#log",
                max: 10,
                accept: 'jpg|png|gif|jpeg',
                STRING: {
                    file: '<p>$file</p>',
                    remove: '<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Hapus </button>'
                }

            });
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Now, this is the html page :

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('', array('id' => 'upload', 'enctype' => "multipart/form-data")); ?>
  <div class="form-group col-sm-12 ">
    <label for="file">Upload Foto</label>
    <input name="file[]" id="file" class=" btn" type="file" multiple >    
    <div class="col-sm-6" id="log"> </div>
   </div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
 <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

I use ajax to submit this photo like this :

```
$('#upload').submit(function () {
        $.blockUI();
        var form = $('#upload');
        var inputFile = $('input#file');
        var filesToUpload = inputFile[0].files;

        // make sure there is file(s) to upload
        if (filesToUpload.length > 0) {
            // provide the form data that would be sent to sever through ajax
            var formData = new FormData();

            for (var i = 0; i < filesToUpload.length; i++) {
                var file = filesToUpload[i];
                formData.append("file[]", file, file.name);
            }

             $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo base_url('surveyor/c_surveyor/add_file_image/'); ?>/" + response.Nama_file + response.No_inspection,
                type: 'post',
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (obj) {

                   $.unblockUI();
                   $(":file").val('');
                   $(":text").val('');
                   $("#comments").val('');
                   $(".MultiFile-label").empty();
                   $('#pilih_isotank').before('<div class="callout callout-success lead" id="div_error"><p id="pesan_error">Data Berhasil Terupload dengan Nomor : ' + response.No_inspection + '</p></div>');
                   $('#pilih_isotank').after('<div class="callout callout-success lead" id="div_error"><p id="pesan_error">Data Berhasil Terupload dengan Nomor : ' + response.No_inspection + '</p></div>');
                   $('#div_error').fadeIn("fast");
                   $('#pesan_error').html(obj.Message);
                   $('#div_error').fadeOut(7000);
                   $('input:file').MultiFile('reset');
                   console.log("Update succcess");
                },
                  error: function () {
                    alert('Ada yang salah, press ctrl + r');
                  }
               });

        } else {

            $('#file').after('<div class="callout callout-danger lead" id="div_error"><p id="pesan_error"></p></div>');
            $('#div_error').fadeIn("fast");
            $('#pesan_error').html("Please Choose your Photo...");
            $('#div_error').fadeOut(7000);
            $.unblockUI();
        }
        return false;
    });
```

I have read on doc :there is event : 
    `onFileAppend
    afterFileAppend
    onFileSelect
    afterFileSelect
    onFileRemove
    afterFileRemove`

What should I do. Any help it so appreciated.

Comment: I can suggest you to use "Dropzone" multiple file uploader. I have used it many times, and I am very happy with it.

Comment: dropzone have a the way, when file has choose, it will be live to upload.